# Inexplicable behavior using CALayer to make button round

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I've been using the CALayer of a button to create a round button for a profile image.

I deleted a background image and instead applied a gradient directly to the background of the view of the ViewController that this profile picture sits in, and for some reason my profile image disappeared!  Here is the code that I am using to make the button round:

```
//NSLog(@"Building round layer. proflieImageButton width is: %f", _profileImageButton.imageView.frame.size.width);
CALayer *imageLayer = _profileImageButton.layer;
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:_profileImageButton.frame.size.width/2];
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
[imageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:195.0 green:195.0 blue:195.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

I did not touch this code, but when I ran it, my background of the VC was set properly but my button was gone. I could still tap the space it was supposed to be in to go to the profile screen, and it was properly sized judging by taping from the edge of the screen to find where the hit box is.

I tried using `[_profileImageButton setClipsToBounds:YES]` as well but that led to the same result. I commented out the `setMasksToBounds` call, and the image was there, correctly positioned and sized, but not rounded of course.

So, I added that commented out NSLog. However, first I had it printing `_profileImageButton.frame.size.width`.  When I did that, I got 1000.0, though the profile image was still gone.

Then, I decided to see if the size of the frame on the button and the imageView on the button are the same, so I set it to what you see above, though not commented out... the size is 0, *but*, the profile button appears as expected, round and properly sized!

Commenting out that NSLog reverses this. I have no idea what's causing it, or why it stopped working in the first place, but could anybody explain what may be going on so I can ensure it's not something that could potentially break within my code?

Now, that's not the end of things.

When you push the button, you go to the Profile View Controller. On this VC, I also display the profile Image in a similar fashion, except that it is just a UIImageView instead of wrapped into a button. When the profile button from the menu broke, it also broke the profile image within the profile. This one, since it doesn't have a separate imageView, is not working this same way. I can't get it to appear at all.

Here is the very similar code snipper I have on that View Controller, which used to work when I removed the background image of the menu, but no longer will.

```
    NSLog(@"Building round layer. profileImageView width is: %f", _profileImageView.frame.size.width);
//Make the Profile Image round
CALayer *imageLayer = _profileImageView.layer;
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:_profileImageView.frame.size.width/2];
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
[imageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:195.0 green:195.0 blue:195.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Any idea what's going on at all?

Comment: In what place(method) are you rounding your view?

Comment: Something like Reveal would be very helpful here. What do you see in the Xcode's view debugger when all this is happening?

Comment: @Volodymyr this is in the ViewController's viewDidLoad method

Comment: @jrturton I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to display at all. I can view it when I put a breakpoint at the beginning of viewDidLoad, but further down it just loads endlessly when I try to view it.

Comment: in viewDidLoad method your views has not correct sizes. Remove your code into viewDidLayoutSubviews. It should help.

Comment: @Volodymyr Any idea why the NSLog accessing the image view of the button makes it work properly? Think it just delays things long enough to get accurate sizes?

Comment: We have a winner. Post it as an answer and I'll mark you as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting that background image breaking these is odd, though. Again, I wonder if the extra time just made it so that this snippet didn't get called until things were laid out properly? I don't get code sometimes.

Comment: Probably you are right and that is because of delay. Still it's just a guess. I'm almost sure that it may not work on other device etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` method your views has not correct sizes. Remove your code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It should help.